# create an android bluetooth-multiplayer game

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to create an android multiplayer game where one device can be used as a bluetooh server/host and up to 7 devices(from what i've heard that is the max bluetooth connecntions number that possible) will be able to connect to the device and be synced in the game. my question is if such thing is practical, because i dont know much about bluetooth.
I also want to know why the max connections is 7

Comment: Just use Google Play Games multiplayer, you will get more features out of the box, together with a nice Play Games Badge for your PlayStore listing. Rolling your own Bluetooth based protocol will be much harder and much more error prone.

Answer (score 1):

Just use Google Play Games multiplayer, you will get more features out of the box, together with a nice Play Games Badge for your PlayStore listing. Rolling your own Bluetooth based protocol will be much harder and much more error prone. The seven devices limit is a limit of the Bluetooth standard itslef, not an Android limit. The seven devices will have to share the bandwith of one EDR connection (about 2.1 MBit/s) which leads to 0.3 MBit/s per client which is pretty slow.